# How can i add sequence no using awk to any input file?

Tags: awk, sequence

Suppose i am having following data in a file name Details.txt:

```
0154 Raghav Sharma 26 Indore 
0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0018 sai    kanak  28 mumbai
0159 rakh   patid     Pune
0159 sarak  jatid     Pune
```

now i have applied following awk command for generating 4 digit sequence no:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=1;OFS="    "}/^/{$1=sprintf("%04d",a);++a;print $0; next;}{print $0}' Details.txt
```

output:

```
0001 0154 Raghav Sharma 26 Indore 
0002 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0003 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0004 0018 sai    kanak  28 mumbai
0005 0159 rakh   patid Pune
0006 0159 sarak  jatid Pune
```

the formatting of last two rows are disturbed.Please suggest a way,so that
proper formatting along with correct sequence no can be maintained.

Answer (score 4):

You want to avoid recomputing $0; if you do, multiple spaces will be condensed to a single space:

```
$ cat Details.txt
0154 Raghav Sharma 26 Indore
0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0018 sai    kanak  28 mumbai
0159 rakh   patid     Pune
0159 sarak  jatid     Pune

$ gawk '{printf "%04d %s\n", NR, $0}' Details.txt
0001 0154 Raghav Sharma 26 Indore
0002 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0003 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0004 0018 sai    kanak  28 mumbai
0005 0159 rakh   patid     Pune
0006 0159 sarak  jatid     Pune
```

Comment: nice use of `NR`... and I didn't read the question properly :-/

Answer (score 2):

```
$ # nl command is more apt for numbering files
$ nl -s' ' --number-format=rz -w4 ip.txt
0001 0154 Raghav Sharma 26 Indore 
0002 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0003 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0004 0018 sai    kanak  28 mumbai
0005 0159 rakh   patid     Pune
0006 0159 sarak  jatid     Pune

$ # with awk, leaving this as an alternate to printf solution 
$ awk '{sub(/^/, sprintf("%04d ",++c))} 1' ip.txt
0001 0154 Raghav Sharma 26 Indore 
0002 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0003 0159 rakh   patid  24 Pune
0004 0018 sai    kanak  28 mumbai
0005 0159 rakh   patid     Pune
0006 0159 sarak  jatid     Pune
```

- using `sub` here to insert text at beginning of line

  - Changing `$1` will force `$0` to be re-aligned using `OFS` whereas `sub` will leave rest of the contents as is
  - This particular problem happens to be solvable using this simple trick. In general, use [Processing Fixed-Width Data using FIELDWIDTHS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html) if you have `gawk`
- `sprintf("%04d ",++c))` by default, uninitialized variables will be `0` in numeric context (or just use `NR` as shown in other answer)
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0`